# Algorithm for translating MLB play-by-play records into descriptive text

Tags: algorithm, parsing, nlp, language-agnostic, finite-automata

I'm trying to collect a dataset that could be used for automatically generating baseball articles.

I have play-by-play records of MLB games from [retrosheet.org](https://www.retrosheet.org/) that I would like to be written out to plain text, as those that could possibly appear as part of a recap news article.

Here are some examples of the play-by-play records:

```
play,2,0,semim001,32,.CBFFFBBX,9/F
play,2,0,phegj001,01,FX,S7/G
play,2,0,martn003,01,CX,3/G
play,2,1,youne003,00,,NP
```

The following is what I would like to achieve: 
For the first example 
`play,2,0,semim001,32,.CBFFFBBX,9/F`,

I want it to be written out as something like:

*"semim001 (Marcus Semien) was on three balls and two strikes in the second inning as the away player. He hit the ball into play after one called strike, one ball, three fouls, and another two balls. The fly ball was caught by the right outfielder."*

The plays are formatted in the following way:

1. The first field is the inning, an integer starting at 1.
2. The second field is either 0 (for visiting team) or 1 (for home team).
3. The third field is the Retrosheet player id of the player at the plate.
4. The fourth field is the count on the batter when this particular event (play) occurred. Most Retrosheet games do not have this information, and in such cases, "??" appears in this field.
5. The fifth field is of variable length and contains all pitches to this batter in this plate appearance and is described below. If pitches are unknown, this field is left empty, nothing is between the commas.
6. The sixth field describes the play or event that occurred.

Explanations for all the symbols in the fifth and sixth field can be found on this [Retrosheet page.](https://www.retrosheet.org/eventfile.htm)

With Python 3, I've been able to format all the info of invariable length into a formatted sentence, which is all but the last two fields. I'm having difficulty in thinking of an efficient way to unparse (correct me if this is the wrong term to use here) the fifth and sixth fields, the pitches and the events that occurred, due to their variable length and wide variety of things that can occur.

I think I could write out all the rules based on the info on the Retrosheet website, but I'm looking for suggestions for a smarter way to do this. I wrote natural language processing as tags, hoping this could be a trivial problem in that field. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know you tagged this Python, but you might have done better with [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info).

Comment: Since this is not a Python answer I will not post it as an answer. If you use Prolog [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) which while useful for parsing, text -> AST, in this case you would use it in the other direction, AST->text, but your AST are even simpler than a tree, they are just a list.

Comment: @GuyCoder thank you for your comments. I'll look into Prolog. It seems like [PySWIP](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip) enables us to use SWI Prolog through Python!

Comment: Prolog is not something you will just pick up and will be able to use. It uses syntactic unification; there is no variable assignment. If this is for work don't plan on setting an expected date for completion and expect to meet it. If you are planning on learning Prolog on your own, prepare to be confused and frustrated.

Comment: Why don't you just save yourself some trouble and just make use of formatted printing. I haven't done Python in a while so I can't give an example without looking it up, but that is how I would go if there was a limited amount of time.

Comment: @GuyCoder I don't think formatted printing is going to cut it, without a lot of hardcoding. I've used it for simpler plays but once it gets complicated, I have to add a lot of "if else" statements and was wondering if there was a more elegant way to implement this logic with a finite state machine. I was looking into Prolog and it definitely looks like something I'll have to invest a lot of time to be able to make use of it for my purposes.

Comment: OK. Prolog should should work, but learning Prolog without a teacher or experienced mentor is not easy. Many people just give up before getting even to some basics.